# disabling all remote administration

Tags: remote

I have been having trouble with family memebrs not respecting my privacy.

I know from my it days you can do all sorts of stuff remotely as long as you know the machine name via powershell and sc. e.g. remotely start windows services using sc.

Is there a way I can completely lock down all this kind of stuff so my pc doesn't respond to this?

I have already changed my workgroup and installed software firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advanced System Properties (Control Panel or My Computer, Properties), Remote tab and turn OFF (Disable) BOTH sections of this tab so no one can access the computer. This is in addition to what you have done.  Make sure no one has installed Team Viewer, Radmin or like on your computer and uninstall this (or change the passwords to this) to lock down further

Comment: You can also disable Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) Service from the Services CPL. See http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/